# Pasar id en un modal ionic Framework v1

Tags: ionic, entity-framework

hola buenas tardes me encuentro con el siguiente problema tengo el sigueinte listado que esta cargado con un objeto json, el cual a cada elemento le tengo adjuntado un boton de editar y eliminar

```
<div class="item item-divider bar bar-dark" >Listado de Pedido</div>
     <body>
   <form>
     <div class="item item-body">



          <ion-item ng-repeat="pedido in pedido">

     <h2>N°{{pedido.id_menu}}  Fecha:{{pedido.fecha}}</h2>
     <p>{{pedido.proveedor}}</p>
     <p>{{pedido.comida}}</p>
     <p>{{pedido.postre}}</p>
     <p>{{pedido.precio}}</p>
          <a class="button button-small button-assertive ion-trash-a" ng-click="BorrarPedido(pedido.id_menu)"> Eliminar</a>
          <a class="button button-small button-positive ion-edit" ng-click="openModal (pedido.id_menu)"> Editar</a>
           </ion-item>

        </ion-list>
     </form>
   </body>
```

y le asigne un modal para que una vez seleccionado el que quiero editar me habra dicho modal con los datos a editar

```
<script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
     <ion-header-bar>

            <h1 class="title">Editar Pedido</h1>
            <button class="button button-icon   ion-close-circled" ng-click="modal.hide()">
            </button>
          </div>
        </ion-header-bar>
       <ion-content ng-repeat="pedido in pedido"> 
                    <div class="list">

                      <label class="item item-input">
                        <span class="input-label" ng-model="pedido.id_menu">Nro :{{pedido.id_menu }}
                      </label>
                      <label class="item item-input">
                        <span class="input-label" ng-model="pedido.fecha">Fecha: {{pedido.fecha}} </span>
                      </label>
                        <label class="item item-input">
                        <span class="input-label">Proveedor :</span>
                            <input type="text"  ng-model="pedido.proveedor">

                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input">
                        <span class="input-label">Comida :</span>
                            <input type="text"  ng-model="pedido.comida">
                        </label>
                       <label class="item item-input">
                        <span class="input-label">Postre :</span>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="pedido.postre">
                        </label>
                       <label class="item item-input">
                        <span class="input-label">Precio :</span>
                            <input type="text"  ng-model="pedido.precio">
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    <button class="button button-positive button-block" ng-click="Editar(pedido,id_menu)">
                            Guardar
                        </button>



  </ion-modal-view>
```

y el siguiente controlador

```
.controller('MostrarPedidoCtrl',function($scope,$http,$state,$ionicPopup,$ionicModal){

$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'

  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
   $scope.openModal = function(id_menu) {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {

    $scope.modal.hide();
  }
```

el tema es que cuando selecciono en el modal emergente, el modal me carga mas de una vez el elegido y no me deja modificar, por favor me darian una ayuda de como seria la manera correcta de pasar el id, necesito solucionarlo desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
$scope.openModal = function(id_menu) {
    $scope.id_menu = id_menu;
    $scope.modal.show();
};
```

A tu modal ya la estas pasando el padre `$scope` por lo tanto podras acceder a sus valores desde el modal.

Comment: eso ya lo hacia,pero igual me hace lo mismo en la vista y no entiendo por que, cuando en el listado elijo la primera opcion se me abre el modal con el id que elegi pero si  hago un scroll sin querer se carga en el modal automaticamente el siguiente objeto con el id siguiente  y si cierro  el modal y vuelvo a eligir el de arriba , se carga automaticamente el de abajo, eso tambien no se como hacer de que cuando se cierre el modal se limpie el modal.

Comment: eso parece ser otro error y no de la data en el modal, recibes algun log en consola?

Comment: no,mira si me das un mail te paso el proyecto si queres y lo miras, y me decis que te parece.